# which registers is changed when we move from user mode to kernel mode ?! and what is the reason to move to kernel mode?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, computer-science

which registers is changed when we move from user mode to kernel mode ?! and what is the reason to move to kernel mode ?

why these reasons aren't cause moving to kernel mode :

1. make new admin by root ( super user or admin)
2. If i get TLB miss why we don't move to kernel mode
3. when we write to bit Page modified in the Page tables

Answer (score 0):

From your questions i found that you are very poor in operating system concepts.
Ok let me explain,(I am assuming you are using linux not windows).

"which registers is changed when we move from user mode to kernel mode ?" 
       For knowing answer for this question you need to learn about process management.
But i can simply say, linux uses system call interface for changing from user space to kernel space. system call interface uses some registers (Based on your processor) to pass system call number and arguments for system call.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the move to kernel mode happens when

- you make an explicit request to the kernel (a system call)
- you make an implicit request to the kernel (accessing memory that isn't mapped into your space, whether valid or not)
- the kernel decides it needs to do something more important than executing your code (normally as the result of a hardware interrupt).

All registers will be preserved, as it would be rather difficult to write code if your registers could change at random, but **how** that happens is very CPU specific.

Answer (score 0):

"which registers is changed when we move from user mode to kernel mode ?!"

In a typical x86 based architecture running linux kernel, this is what happens:

1. a software program shall trigger interrupt 0x80 by the instruction: int $0x80
2. The CPU will change the program counter register & the code selector to refer to
   the place where linux system call handler exists in memory (linux applies virtual
   memory concept).
3. Till now registers affected are: CS, EIP, and EFLAGS register. the CPU also changes
   Stack Selector (SS) and Stack Pointer (ESP) to refer to the top of kernel stack.
4. Finally, the kernel changes the Data Selector and Extra Data Selector (DS & ES) to
   select to a kernel mode data segment.
5. The kernel shall push the program context on kernel's stack and the general purpose
   registers (like accumulators) will change due to the kernel code being executed.

So as you can see, it all depends on the operating system and the architecture.

"and what is the reason to move to kernel mode ?"

The CPU by default works in kernel mode, your question should be "what is the need of user mode?". The user mode is necessary because it doesn't provide all permissions to the running software. You can run your browser/file manager/shell in user mode without any worries. If full permissions are given to application software, they will access the kernel data and damage it, and they might also access the hardware and for example, destroy the data stored on your hard disk.

Kernel of course must work in kernel mode (at least the core of the kernel). Application software for example, might require to write data to a file on the disk. application software doesn't have access to the disk (because it is running in user mode). the only way to achieve this is to call the kernel (which is running in kernel mode) to do the job. that's why you need to move from user mode to kernel mode and vice versa.